# Access turtle data from matrix in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to get turtles to fight each other in an ABM with netlogo. At the moment the turtles randomly move each tick.  I want them to randomly find another turtle at each tick and fight them. Ultimately, I will have them only fight neighbors, but at the moment pairing is random.

The winner of the fight is determined by the win probability between each pair of turtles. I am used to doing these models in R where I would store this info in a matrix.  e.g.

```
[[    1  0.95  0.95 ]
 [ 0.05     1  0.75 ]
 [ 0.05  0.25     1 ]]
```

Here, the turtle in the first row is 95% likely to win against the turtle in column 2 or 3.  Turtle in row 2 is 5% likely to win against columnA and 75% likely  to win against columnC.  I've put 1's down the diagonal, but turtles cannot fight themselves.  Over time the turtles lose energy from fighting - but this is not added to the model just yet.

This is my code thus far.  When I pick the turtles to find a 'victim', I want to be able to pick the pair of win probabilities from this matrix.  e.g. if I picked turtle0 and turtle3 as the victim, I want to simulate  a 'fight' whereby turtleA is the winner with a 95% win probability.

Is using a matrix in this way the best way to do this in netlogo? or am I using my other programming language biases too much?

```
extensions [matrix]

globals []

turtles-own [
  energy ;;  energy level
  ]

to setup
  ca

  let m matrix:from-row-list [[1 .95 .95] [.05 1 .75] [.05 .25 1] ]
  print matrix:pretty-print-text m ;;just to check if matrix is correct

  crt 3 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color 11
    set shape "mouse side"
    set size  2
  ]
  ask patches [
    set pcolor 66
  ]
  ask turtles [
    set energy 100
    ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
   if ticks >= 5000 [ stop ]  ;; stop after 5000 runs.

  ask turtles [
   fd 5 rt random 90
  check-death
  check-fight
  ]
  tick
end



;; if energy gets to 0 die.
to check-death
    if energy <= 0 [ die ]
end



to check-fight

    let victim one-of turtles-here

    if victim != nobody

        [
   ;; code in here to get win probabilities  from matrix and determine winner.   
         ]

    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is using a matrix in this way the best way to do this in netlogo?

In a word: no. What you're trying to represent using a matrix is in fact a weighted network of fighting odds. NetLogo has built-in support for modeling networks, so you'd be much better off using that.

See the **Links** sections of the [NetLogo Programing Guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links) and of the [NetLogo Dictionary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#linkgroup) for more details on networks.

Here is a stripped down version of your code, using links:

```
directed-link-breed [ odds odd ]
odds-own [ probability ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3
  ask turtles [
    create-odds-to other turtles [
      set probability random-float 1.0
      hide-link
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    fd 5 rt random 90
    fight 
  ]
  tick
end

to fight
  if any? other turtles-here [
    let victim one-of other turtles-here
    let p [ probability ] of out-odd-to victim
    if random-float 1.0 < p [
      print (word self " wins against " victim)
    ]
  ]
end
```

That version uses random probabilities as the fighting odds, but you could just as well initialize those from a list or a matrix.

Here is an example using your original matrix (with the diagonal stripped out):

```
to init-odds
  let m [
    [ 0.95  0.95 ]
    [ 0.05  0.75 ]
    [ 0.05  0.25 ]
  ]
  (foreach (sort turtles) m [
    ask ?1 [
      (foreach (sort other turtles) ?2 [
        ask out-odd-to ?1 [ set probability ?2 ]
      ])
    ]
  ])
end
```

I am aware that all the `?1` and `?2` variables make that code hard to follow. You could write something equivalent by relying on `who` numbers, but I don't recommend it: code that uses `who` numbers is generally brittle and error-prone.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks. Thanks for the documentation reference also.